# Why can't JBoss EAP 7.0.0.GA find my EJBs?

Tags: java, jboss

The errors that I am seeing:

```
10:54:25,376 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."xxxEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."upload-api-talon.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."xxxEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."xxx.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "xxx.war" of deployment "xxxEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"
```

More Errors I am seeing:

```
10:54:25,429 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "xxxEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xxxEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"xxx.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xxxEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"xxx.war\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"xxx.war\" of deployment \"xxxEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Failed to link javax/faces/webapp/FacetTag (Module \"deployment.xxxEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.xxx.war:main\" from Service Module Loader): Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/webapp/FacetTag"},
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"xxxEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\".transient-store-data.TransientMetadataStorageImpl.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"xxxEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\".transient-store-data.TransientMetadataStorageImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"xxxEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\".transient-store-logic.StoreTrustedDocumentsInTransient.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"xxxEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\".transient-store-logic.StoreTrustedDocumentsInTransient]",
```

It looks like it is saying that it can't find my classes, but it can find my jars.  How is that possible?

I see this log as well indicating that it can find the Library:

```
10:54:25,408 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'QuarantineTransientMetadataStorageImpl' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "transient-store-data.jar" of deployment "upload-api-talonEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"' are as follows:

        java:global/upload-api-talonEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/transient-store-data/QuarantineTransientMetadataStorageImpl!com.usaa.api.enterprise.contentstorage.data.connectors.IQuarantineMetadataStorage
        java:app/transient-store-data/QuarantineTransientMetadataStorageImpl!com.usaa.api.enterprise.contentstorage.data.connectors.IQuarantineMetadataStorage
        java:module/QuarantineTransientMetadataStorageImpl!com.usaa.api.enterprise.contentstorage.data.connectors.IQuarantineMetadataStorage
        java:global/upload-api-talonEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/transient-store-data/QuarantineTransientMetadataStorageImpl
        java:app/transient-store-data/QuarantineTransientMetadataStorageImpl
        java:module/QuarantineTransientMetadataStorageImpl
```

Honestly, the log is all over the place

Comment: Can you update your question with whats shown in the server.log file or console when the EAR gets deployed?

Answer (score 0):

If you deploying EJBs, it should be packed as JAR and should have ejb-jar.xml as descriptor. I don't think we can pack EJBs  along with web appliaction file.

**Typical Structure:**

EAR

- WARs - Web Modules
- JARs - EJBs

Comment: OP's logs say "JNDI bindings for session bean named 'QuarantineTransientMetadataStorageImpl' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "transient-store-data.jar" of deployment "upload-api-talonEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear", so isn't that already correct?

Comment: So I have an ejb-jar.xml in my jars.  I am beginning to wonder if this is even possible to do at all?

Comment: So, I went do the route of repackaging my application into one app.  IE moving the EJB's in the two jars, into just packages inside of my war.  I  removed on dependency at a time until I got the damn thing to deploy.  It was pretty barebones.  I added in more and more dependencies until I found something that broke it.  What I found was that 2 non EJB jars that I had added into my EAR's lib directory were causing that deploy exception that I had up there.  Now Why pray tell  would that be?